# How to hold slope constant with geom_smooth drawing trend lines for groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I cannot find an obvious solution in `ggplot2` for a common, trivial statistics problem. I want `geom_smooth(method = "lm")` to hold the slope constant between groups in the `color` aesthetic.

The naive model I begin with is `lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)`. Graphing this in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

To add a control for `Species`, I'd like to test `lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + factor(Species), data = iris`, which holds the slope constant between different species (the model is fitted with one coefficient for sepal length, with only constants varying between species). I'd also like to test `lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Species, data = iris)`, which allows the association between sepal length and sepal width to vary between species.

The second model is trivial to plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

This plot allows the slopes to vary. **Is there a way to prevent the slopes from varying?**

Comment: Do you want only one `lm` through the data?

Answer (score 2):

Your desired result requires some manual work, i.e. estimate the model outside of `ggplot` and add a column with predicted values to your dataframe which could then be plotted using `geom_line`. Same for the other models you   want to test:

```r
library(ggplot2)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$fit <- predict(lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + factor(Species), data = iris2))

ggplot(iris2, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = fit))
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I expected, thank you for the clear example!